# Make JSON available for later use

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I am trying to build a simple autocomplete feature.

My first intention was to query a specific database with a `%like%` statement every time the user adds or deletes a character in an `<input>`, then displaying the result.

But I would like to prevent this heavy database usage by, for example, fetching a JSON and then using that.

How could I make that JSON file available to my jQuery script?

Comment: So you want to download your database to JSON then query the JSON instead?

Comment: Which server side language are you using ?

Comment: There is no straight forward, out of the box way to do it on the client site, especailly if the dataset/database in question is large, which in most cases is. Most of the popular web services and sites, prefer to cache the results on server side using a  solution like memcache, redis, etc. They are very very fast and reduce the overhead of fetching data for repeat queries drastically.

Comment: When I create an autocomplete feature, I usually delay the search until a couple hundred milliseconds after they start typing. This reduces the number of queries and waits till the user is likely done typing to run the search. I then implement a cancel function for any existing calls if the user types something new.

Comment: @Tom
Yip, that is correct.
Your idea of delaying sounds like a good workaround, but nevertheless i'd like to figure out this here

Comment: To everyone, my further approach was using $.ajax(), but i will take the answers below as a guideline. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you know that the results of your autocomplete lookup shouldn't change each time, you can cache the results into an object as described on the jQuery UI [Autocomplete demo page](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache):

```
$(function () {
    var cache = {};
    $("#birds").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            if (term in cache) {
                response(cache[term]);
                return;
            }
            $.getJSON("search.php", request, function (data, status, xhr) {
                cache[term] = data;
                response(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It sounds like you want to load the full JSON results up front before the user starts typing anything, though.  In that case, simply load the JSON object up front like this when the page first loads:

```
$.getJSON("search.php", request, function (data, status, xhr) {
    cache[term] = data;
    response(data);
});
```

And then use the local object ("cache" in the example above) as the source for your autocomplete lookup (see the [default](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) and [custom display](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) autocomplete demos for your main options there), e.g., something like this:

```
$("#autocompleteInput").autocomplete({
    source: cache
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this by executing your query, encoding the value with `json_encode()`, then printing the value within your HTML in a JavaScript block, à la:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php

    echo 'var json_values = \'' . $json_encoded_values . '\'';

?>
</script>
```

...which will then allow you to work with `json_values` as you see fit in your script.

Before you go down that route, however, I'd suggest that you look into [jQuery UI's Autocomplete API](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/); it will more intelligently / efficiently search for items as the user is typing (with appropriate pauses, etc) - instead of doing a query every time the user changes the field.

It seems unlikely that a simple `LIKE` query would add *that* much overhead to your database, even if queried frequently.